# Proper syntax for MS GraphAPI filter IN operator

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to simplify a GraphAPI request to get a list of mail folders based on a `displayName` filter. This seems to work with the `eq` operator but not with `in`. Below are the two requests, which should return the same result.

Using `eq`:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders?$filter=displayName eq 'inbox' or displayName eq 'drafts'`

Using `in`:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders?$filter=displayName in ('inbox', 'drafts')`

When using `in` I get the error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-02-16T16:48:51",
            "request-id": "",
            "client-request-id": ""
        }
    }
}
```

From the documentation I've read in should be supported wherever eq is supported by default. Syntax should be correct based on examples I found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#examples-using-the-filter-query-operator

Can someone shed some light on what the issue might be?

Comment: The error message indicates that this kind of filter is not  supported I think, so I searched for the mail folder properties and found that there's no description on if this is not supported. But I found the [OData Protocol](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358) and found there's no `in` method...

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement applies only to directory objects (resources that are documented as inheriting from the directoryObject resource.
mailFolder isn't one of them

Comment: I think you're probably right. The documentation is not exactly clear about support for the ``in`` operator but the general rule of it being supported wherever ``eq`` is supported most likely applies only to directory objects

Answer (score 0):

for inbox for example, you can use directly this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0